# How to prevent Lubuntu to launch lxpanel on startup?

Tags: lxde, autostart, lxpanel

Couldn't find a `@lxpanel` command in the several `autostart` files distributed in a live version of Lubuntu 16.04, so I'm wondering where is it specify that the panel has to be created when the session starts. You can always kill it afterwards with a `lxpanelctl exit`, but would prefer to not even start it, so as to reduce overall startup time.

Comment: Did you try this? **Type (use copy/paste):**
**cd /etc/xdg/autostart/**

Then:
**sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop**       And after that, check the startup applications, all of them should be listed.

Comment: After doing it I see the same 14 files, namely: `blueman.desktop                 nm-applet.desktop
gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop    polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop   print-applet.desktop
gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop       pulseaudio.desktop
gsettings-data-convert.desktop  update-notifier.desktop
indicator-application.desktop   user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop
light-locker.desktop            xfce4-power-manager.desktop`, and `grep` does not detect any call to `lxpanel` there.